# Simple: Loop through dropdown menu, paste values in new workbook

Tags: vba, excel, loops, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu in cell A1 on Sheet1 (Sales Locations) that has ~20 objects. Everyone of them changes the data in the sheet below from A2:P115. The same thing happens on Sheet20 (OSRs). These both need to be copied over to a new workbook. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...I sure hope I'm not reading this incorrectly, but it appears that all data is self-contained within each sheet.  Under that understanding, I say, Right-click on the sheet tab, then choose "Move or Copy", select the "Copy" checkbox, then select New Workbook from the upper drop-down.  Last, select OK.  Repeat for all required sheets.  Is that what you need?

Comment: I actually figured it out, but thanks for getting back to me!